# How to find all ERROR logs greater than a variable timestamp?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a shell script smoke test that will accept an optional variable length timestamp parameter (2019-08-08 22:35:02,846), search through logs and show all ERROR lines greater than this timestamp.  If no timestamp is provided it should search through the entire file instead.

For example, "2019-08-07" would find all error lines greater than this day.  "2019-08-07 05" would find all error lines greater than this hour, "2019-08-07 05:23" greater than this minute, etc.

Running the line right below directly in the console works as expected.  It will only print out the lines after this date.  However when I try doing this in a shell script and pass the timestamp as a variable parameter it will print every error from the entire log instead.

```
echo "`grep 'ERROR' "/some-directory/some.log" | awk '$0 > "2019-08-07\ 04:00"'`"
```

I think the problem lies around the awk command.  I've tried putting the timestamp variable in single quotes, double, parenthesis but I can't get it to reproduce the same output that the command line does.

I've also tried converting the timestamp being passed in to escape the space if it includes one as different awk methods I have tried complain if it sees a space.

```
TIME="$(echo $1 | sed 's/ /\\ /g')"
```

```
# Code that I'm trying...
TIME="$1"
SEARCH="ERROR"
LOG="/some-directory/some.log"
RESULT="$(grep $SEARCH $LOG | (awk '$0 > $TIME'))"
echo "$RESULT"
```

Example of how logs are formatted...

```
2019-08-07 00:50:54,526 [blah] ERROR blah blah blah
2019-08-07 01:40:54,527 [blah] INFO blah blah blah
2019-08-07 05:04:06,837 [blah] ERROR blah blah blah
2019-08-08 02:23:15,838 [blah] WARNING blah blah blah
2019-08-08 22:35:02,846 [blah] ERROR blah blah blah
```

When passed a timestamp of "2019-08-07 04:00" the output should be...

```
2019-08-07 05:04:06,837 [blah] ERROR blah blah blah
2019-08-08 22:35:02,846 [blah] ERROR blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
RESULT="$(grep "$SEARCH" "$LOG" | awk ""\$0" > \"$TIME\"")"
```

or

```
RESULT=$(grep "$SEARCH" "$LOG" | awk ""\$0" > \"$TIME\"")
```

or

```
RESULT=$(grep "$SEARCH" "$LOG" | awk -v TIME="$TIME" '$0 > TIME')
```

Comment: Thank you!  All great suggestions and solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The `$TIME` in the `awk` command isn't quoted correctly so it isn't being expanded by `bash`.

Try

```
$ cat some.sh
TIME="$1"
SEARCH="ERROR"
LOG="some.log"
RESULT=$(grep $SEARCH $LOG | awk '$0 > "'"$TIME"'"')
echo "$RESULT"
IT070137 ~/tmp/stackoverflow $ bash some.sh "2019-08-07 04:00"
2019-08-07 05:04:06,837 [blah] ERROR blah blah blah
2019-08-08 22:35:02,846 [blah] ERROR blah blah blah
```

Comment: How did you know it was being expanded?  Sorry I'm new to shell scripts.  I assume the $0 is referencing the first column in the line?  I just am not sure if it's picking up the date or the date and time since there is a space in between them.

I tried your variation and I get the error below.  
`awk: \$0 >= $TIME  
awk: ^ backslash not last character on line`

Comment: I'm guessing you tried that on the command line. Try it in the script

Comment: No, it was in the script that I ran with a command such as `smoke-test.sh "2019-08-07 04:00"`

Comment: If you want to reproduce it you can probably take the logs sample and the code and run it as is.

Comment: @Coolbreeze78 Sorry, I was misreading the double quotes around the `$()`. It turn out they aren't significant, and it was the single quotes around the `awk` script which were the problem. They were preventing $TIME being expanded by `bash`.

Comment: Nice! That seemed to have fixed it.  Thanks for the help!  Not sure how you figured all that out.  I was starting to read through all the documentation on awk since everything I tried didn't work.